# Execution a list of functions with Ursina

Tags: python, animation, ursina, rubiks-cube

I'm writing Python code to solve the Rubik's cube The output is a list of rotations. In other hand I have an interface made with Ursina that shows the cube and can be interacted with using The keyboard. My question is how can I bring the cube to follow the solution from the first code and execute these rotations one after the other only with one button click? Which function in Ursina can I use?

Comment: If you have a list of functions, you can do `for f in list_of_funcs: f(arguments)`

Answer (score 0):

First you start by making the function:

```
def solve(list_, cube):

    for move in list_:

        #Here you apply one rotation (move) to the cube
```

Later you create a "input" function to detect the key binding

```
def input(key):

    if key == "S": #You can put the key you want

       solve(your_list, your_cube)
```

Because I don't know how you made the cube rotate in your program, I can't give you are more detailed answer, but if you want, you can send me the program here: btmmaiboxes@gmail.com